# Is there a split function that returns [] in this case?

Tags: python, list, split

Of course we have:

```
"1,2,3".split(",")  # ["1", "2", "3"]
"1".split(",")      # ["1"]
```

but also this, which is sometimes problematic in some situations (*):

```
"".split(",")       # [""]
```

Is there a built-in way (maybe with a parameter, or a specific function) to have:

```
"".split(",", allow_empty=True)       # []
```

?

This would (sometimes) make sense: **the input is empty, so the output list should be empty.**

(*) Example situation:

```
for element in s.split(","):
    print(f"we have the element {element}")

# works for s = "1, 2, 3"
# works for s = "1"
# doesn't work for s = ""  => the loop should be empty
```

Comment: You can always write such a function, should not take more than one line.

Comment: Sure @jurez, I already did. Out of curiosity, for beauty of code, I wondered if this is maybe included somewhere :)

Comment: @Basj, do you need this mainly for correct looping/iterating?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to my knowledge but you could use a regex with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

re.findall(r'[^,]+', '1,2,3')
# ['1', '2', '3']

re.findall(r'[^,]+', '1')
# ['1']

re.findall(r'[^,]+', '')
# []
```

Note that this would also discard empty strings within the input string:

```
re.findall(r'[^,]+', '1,,3')
# ['1', '3']
```

Answer (score 2):

To ensure non-empty iterator (for looping) you can rely on [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) builtin function:

```
s = "" 
for element in filter(None, s.split(",")):
    print(f"we have the element {element}")

# nothing is printed
```

From `filter(function, iterable)` doc:

> If `function` is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of `iterable` that are false are removed.

Comment: Please beware that this will do (maybe) unexpected things for `'1,,2'`: only `1` and `2` will be printed, skipping empty element.

Comment: Thanks! Why does `filter(None, ...)` work in this case? I know that we usually use `filter(function, iterable)`, but why does passing `None` as the function allows `filter` to transform `[""]` into `[]` and not change anything to `["1", "2"]`?

Comment: @Basj, from doc: "*If function is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.*"

Comment: @Basj As you can read in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter); "**If function is None**, the identity function is assumed, that is, **all elements of iterable that are false are removed**."

Answer (score 2):

To split a string with a fixed single-character separator you can use `csv.reader`:

```
import csv

print(next(csv.reader(['1,2,3'])))
print(next(csv.reader(['1,,3'])))
print(next(csv.reader(['1'])))
print(next(csv.reader([''])))
```

This outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['1', '', '3']
['1']
[]
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCG5uIyLq6AoM69EIy@1okQDyNcrSk1MSS3SiFY31DHSMVaP1dTUxKOEoAr80mDZ//8B)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `filter()` for this.

```
x = "".split(",")
y = list(filter(None, x))

print(x, y) #[''] []
```

Comment: Interesting! Why does `filter(None, ...)` work in this case? I know that we usually use `filter(function, iterable)`, but why does passing `None` as the function allows `filter` to transform `[""]` into `[]` and not change anything to `["1", "2"]`?

Comment: If the function passed to filter() is None, the identity function is assumed as specified in the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter . In short, it filters out any None/False values from the array.

Comment: Note that this also has the side effect of not preserving empty strings in the middle, e.g. `'1,,3'` becomes `['1', '3']`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `s.split(",")[not s:]` which leverages the truthy value of the string itself to skip the empty item in the result when the string is empty:

```
testCases = ["1,2,3","1,3","1",""]

for s in testCases:
        result = s.split(",")[not s:]
        print(repr(s), '-->', repr(result))

'1,2,3' --> ['1', '2', '3']
'1,3' --> ['1', '3']
'1' --> ['1']
'' --> []
```

*Of course this is not a parameter pre se, but it almost reads like one by adding a kind of option to filter the result when there is no `s`*.

If what you are looking for is to exclude all empty entries (i.e. also exclude the empties between consecutive commas `1,,3`), you should use the filter function:

```
*result, = filter(None,s.split(","))
```